# Check if a process such as deletion or update is done through data Loader or any other application using apex

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, data-loader, system

I have a trigger that will call a batch process if my data is updated or deleted.It is working well but the problem is that, when I try to delete my data using data loader, i've encounter and error saying."Attempted to enqueue too many concurrent batch". What I want is to detect if a deletion or update is done by data loader or other application that will process the data through batch. So far I tried to use the `System.isBatch()` but it seems it is not the solution. I still encounter the problem. What is the possible solution for this ? Please help.

Thank you...

Comment: Do you want to know that the DataLoader is doing the update so that you can avoid queuing the Batch operation?

Comment: @martin Yeah. But not only dataloader but also to other application that has the same functionality.

Comment: Do you think there might be a way to bulkify the trigger so that only one batch operation is queued per trigger execution? In other words, were you just trying to get around the error message, or did you really not want the batch to run?

Comment: @martin I didn't understand what you mean. But what i want is to run the trigger only if an operation is not done by data loader or other application that has the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a checkbox field with default value false when you bulk upload your data you can set this checkbox true. If this checkbox is true then your trigger will skip the record and will not run the batch.

There is a workaround you can check Trigger. new size in trigger if it is greater then certain amount then it will be a bulk process. Something like if more then 100 records then it is a bulk process.

Comment: Thanks . But my problem at the moment is that how will i know programatically, that I am having a bulk upload.

Comment: You or any other user who are doing bulk upload are need to set the checkbox value true.

Comment: That's a good idea but is there any way to automatically check if it is a bulk process ? because there are other users that will automatically delete some data using data loader and won't login to salesforce.

Comment: there is a workaround you can check Trigger. new size in trigger if it is greater then certain amount then it will be a bulk process. Something like if more then 100 records then it is a bulk process.

Comment: Thanks bro I tried your idea and it seems it is working. Thank you much...

Comment: If it is work for you then you can mark it as a answer.

Comment: Yeah I voted your comment.Thank you so much...

Comment: i have updated my answer if you want you can accept the answer so it will be mark as completed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [elsewhere on this exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12620/know-data-source), the ideal approach is probably to create a separate user with which to run your data loads.

Comment: This is not an ideal way. There are lots of users in my org. Please read the description. It is quite far from the other question you've said as duplicate.I am not only talking about data loader but also to other application which has the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static variable in your trigger when you schedule the batcch, and verify the static variable before schedule the next time.

**Example**

```
IF(!TriggerHelper.isScheduledBatch){
 System.scheduleBatch(xxxxxxxxx);
TriggerHelper.isScheduleBatch = true;
}
```